# 2 classes, 1 Junit test error in Java. Error message

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and I a new computer science student. I am required to create a JUnit test for Book and Person Class. I know there is an obvious mistake in my code, mind if you point it out? I keep getting an error message no matter what I try.

[image: Java Code]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Please do not add images from code and error messages. Paste the relevant code lines and message text in text format.

Comment: Btw. Next time put the code / error message directly in your question not as images, it is very annoying when you can't copy it to try it out.

Comment: sure! let me just change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On price test you have to set a delta to compare float variables
`assertEquals(100,JavaBook.getPrice(),1)`

Author test isn't correct. You have yo check `assertEquals("John",JavaBook.getAuthor().getFirstName())`

Comment: here's what I did to make it work perfectly, thank you!! Also, what is delta?
  
  public void getPrice() {
    assertEquals(100, JavaBook.getPrice(), 1);
    assertEquals(150, PythonBook.getPrice(),2);

  }

  
  public void getAuthor() {
    assertEquals("John Doe", JavaBook.getAuthor().getFullName());
    assertEquals("Sally Ride", PythonBook.getAuthor().getFullName());

Comment: what is a delta?

Comment: difference amount

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: 
Java tried to convert object *Person* into a String, however your class doesn't override `toString()` method, so it was called from Object class instead. That's why you had this value - Person@22a71081.
You can override method `toString()` so it returns `firstName + " " + lastName`   inside Person class. It should work then.

Comment: First name is John

Comment: unfortunately I cant change anything in person or book class, only junit